# Anylogic - Assembler should stop working for 2 hours after 10 assemblies done

Tags: simulation, anylogic

The "Assembler" should stop working for 2 hours after 10 assemblies are done.
How can I achieve that?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many ways to do this depending on what it means to stop working and what the implications are for the incoming parts.. but here's one option

1. create a resourcePool called Machine, this will be used along with the technicians:
   [image]
2. on the "on exit" action of the assembler do this (I use 9 instead of 10 because the out.count() doesn't count until the agent is completely out, so when it counts 9, it means that you have produced 10)

   if(self.out.count()==9){
   machine.set_capacity(0);
   create_MyDynamicEvent(2, HOUR);
   }
3. In your dynamice event (that you have to create) you will add the following code:

   machine.set_capacity(1);

A second option is to have a variable countAssembler count the number of items produced... then

1. on exit you write countAssembler++;
2. on enter delay you write the following:

   if(countAssembler==10){
   self.suspend(agent);
   create_MyDynamicEvent(2, HOUR,agent);
   }
3. on the dynamic event you write:

   assembler.resume(agent);

Don't forget to add the parameter needed in the dynamic event:
[image: dynamic event]

Comment: I create an integer to count the number of assemblies (e.g. countAssembler) on exit from FA1 (countAssembler++;)and then I have an event triggered by a condition such that when the count of assemblies reaches 10 ((countAssembler==10)), it suspends the FA1 for two hours using suspend function. But how do I implement the suspend function you have ant idea?

Comment: @AqeelTariq i updated the answer with suspend option, but that doesn't stop the machine after 10 items, it stops the 11th agent instead whenever it comes... so the assembler will stop for more than 2 hours... you might want to calculate how much time it has passed since the last item exit, but i won't add that to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable called `countAssembler` of type int. Increment this as agents pass through the assembler. Also create a variable called `assemblerStopTime`. You also record the assembler stop time with `assemblerStopTime=time()`

Place a selectOutputOut block before the and let them in if `countAssembler` value is less than 10. Otherwise send to a `Wait` block.

Now, to maintain the FIFO rule, in the first selectOutputOut condition, you need to check also if there is any agent in the wait block and if the `current time - assemblerStopTime` is greater than 2. If there is, you free it and send to the assembler with `wait.free(0)` function. And send the current agent to wait. You also need to reset the `countAssembler` to zero.

Comment: thank you for your response but can you make the answer move visual like images, that will be easy for me to understand. Looking forward to your positive response.Thank you.